# How to create a DataGrid ItemSource in an async task list

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to get a list as an ItemSource for a DataGrid in wpf. I can get the result from my async method which is like so:

```
public async Task<List<ManualReadTag>> GetManuallyReadTags(ParameterManualTags model { ..... }
```

and I try to have its value displayed in a DataGrid in my MainWindow.xaml like so:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    readonly ApplicationController _ac = new ApplicationController();
    private Task<List<ManualReadTag>> _manualReadTagList = null;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BtnGEtManualCount_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GetManuallyReadTags();
    }

    private void GetManuallyReadTags()
    {
        var model = new ParameterManualTags
        {
            Lane = Convert.ToInt32(TxtLane.Text),
            Plaza = Convert.ToInt32(TxtLane),
            DateTo = DateTo.DisplayDate,
            DateFrom = DateFrom.DisplayDate
        };
         _manualReadTagList = _ac.GetManuallyReadTags(model);
        ViewingGrid.ItemsSource = _manualReadTagList;
    }
}
```

But on the  ViewingGrid.ItemsSource = _manualReadTagList; it gives me an error of:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task>'
>   to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists
>   (are you missing a
>   cast?)    TagReporting    D:\Projects\Lane\Antenna_Reading\TagReporting\TagReporting\MainWindow.xaml.cs   38  Active

How can I use the result from my async Task method as an ItemSource for my datagrid? Thank you.

Comment: You should `await` the `_ac.GetManuallyReadTags(model);` call

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, if `GetManuallyReadTags` is an *async* method it's not named very well, it should have an async suffix `GetManuallyReadTagsAsync` to make it obvious.

Secondly, it's ideal to `await` the *async* call.

```
private async Task GetManuallyReadTagsAsync()
{
    var model = new ParameterManualTags
    {
        Lane = Convert.ToInt32(TxtLane.Text),
        Plaza = Convert.ToInt32(TxtLane),
        DateTo = DateTo.DisplayDate,
        DateFrom = DateFrom.DisplayDate
    };

     _manualReadTagList = await _ac.GetManuallyReadTags(model);
    ViewingGrid.ItemsSource = _manualReadTagList;
}
```

You would also change the type of the `_manualReadTagList` to

```
private List<ManualReadTag> _manualReadTagList;
```

and finally call `GetManuallyReadTagsAsync()` in an async event handler:

```
private async void BtnGEtManualCount_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await GetManuallyReadTagsAsync();
}
```